# How do I cross time series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I've got a dataframe with an integer index:

```
pd.DataFrame([[4,5],[7,8],[9,10]],columns=['a','b'])

    a   b
0   4   5
1   7   8
2   9   10
```

I'd like to create a matrix of ratios for each of `a` cross `b`, for each index, so I get a series of matrices of the form:

```
a/a a/b
b/a b/b
```

for each index. Ultimately, I'll want to unfurl these into four columns.

Is there an easy way? If there's an easy `numpy` solution doing this, that might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way:

```
pd.DataFrame({f'{x}/{y}': df[x] / df[y] for x in df for y in df})
```

Slightly complicated way (might be faster if you have large number of columns):

```
a = df.values[None].T / df.values
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(a), columns=(f'{x}/{y}' for x in df for y in df))
```

Result

```
   a/a    a/b       b/a  b/b
0  1.0  0.800  1.250000  1.0
1  1.0  0.875  1.142857  1.0
2  1.0  0.900  1.111111  1.0
```